# Why does this macro work one way and not the other?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

This is a macro defined in "clx-user-callable.lisp" I'm trying to use.

```
(in-package :clx-gui)

(defmacro get-callback-wrapper (callback)
  (declare (ignorable callback))
  (let* ((func-name (gensym))
         (wrapper-name (intern (format nil "WRAPPER-~a" func-name) )))
    `(defun ,wrapper-name (caller-instance)
       (funcall ,callback) ;; User callbacks wont have arguments
       (closemenu caller-instance))))
```

I call this macro in this manner and it works properly.

```
(in-package :clx-gui-test-app)

(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyEntryDialog"
                      (get-callback-wrapper 'my-callback))

(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyChoiceDialog"
                      (get-callback-wrapper 'my-callback2))

(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyMessageDialog"
                      (get-callback-wrapper 'my-callback3))
```

If I change the code to use the macro this way, by passing the symbol name of the callback to a function that calls the macro, it does not return different wrapper functions, but always returns the same wrapper function. The function that calls the macro is in the same file and package as the macro definition.

```
(in-package :clx-gui-test-app)
(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyEntryDialog" 'my-callback)
(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyChoiceDialog" 'my-callback2)
(create-user-menuitem "MyUserMenu" "MyMessageDialog" 'my-callback3)
```

I have tried adding the package to the macro definition, but that doesn't help.

```
(wrapper-name (intern (format nil "WRAPPER-~a" func-name)
                      (symbol-package callback) )))
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

I'm working with SBCL-1.0.57 and Slime.

Comment: That is because the macro is expanded when the function is compiled, not when it's called.

Comment: Wrap your `create-user-menuitem` function with `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)`.

Comment: Note that the defun/gensym approach isn't guaranteed to create unique function names, b/c two gensyms can be not eq and have the same print value. If you're just trying to define a unique function name that will never be used again, and you don't really care about the name, why not just use lambda?

Comment: @claytontstanley: how come two gensyms would have the same print value?

Comment: Note also that as written, there isn't a reason that this needs to be implemented as a macro. A function would do just fine, b/c the only argument that you're supplying to it is just a quoted symbol.

Comment: @SebastiánBenítez Check out Chapter 3 of Let Over Lambda. But the argument sort of goes, if gensyms were unique by print name, then the print name would have to be infinitely long to have an infinite number of gensyms available. Well that's not practical; so gensym uniqueness isn't based on print name.

Comment: @claytontstanley: I'm not following. Gensyms uniqueness is based on an incrementing accumulator such that every call to gensym creates a new uninterned symbol with a name like G1234. What's the difference between the symbol name and the printed representation appended to WRAPPER- used in the poster's macro?

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER>
(defparameter foo1 (gensym))
FOO1
CL-USER> 
foo1
#:G4619
CL-USER> 
(defparameter foo2 '#:G4619)
FOO2
CL-USER> 
foo2
#:G4619
CL-USER> 
(eq foo1 foo2)
NIL
CL-USER> 
~
```

Or another fun exercise:

```
(defmacro make-fun ()  
  `(defun ,(intern (format nil "WRAPPER-~a" (gensym))) ()
     'bar))

CL-USER> 
(make-fun)
WRAPPER-G4726
CL-USER> 
(make-fun)
WRAPPER-G4730
CL-USER> 
(make-fun)
WRAPPER-G4734
CL-USER> 
(make-fun)
WRAPPER-G4738
CL-USER> 
(defun WRAPPER-G4745 ()
  'foo)
WRAPPER-G4745
CL-USER> 
(make-fun)
WRAPPER-G4745
CL-USER> (wrapper-G4745)
BAR
CL-USER>
```

Oh man, we just wrote over that function!

If you want to notate a gensym with some sort of prefix name, do it in the gensym call (as an optional argument). But all of this is just an exercise, b/c I would still just use lambda in the OP problem.

Here's an alternative implementation that is (IMO) simpler, and should work for your needs:

```
(defun get-callback-wrapper (callback)
  (lambda (caller-instance)
    (funcall callback) 
    (closemenu caller-instance)))
```

This generates the lexical closure that I think you're after.

Comment: Wrap your create-user-menuitem function with (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute). – Sebastián Benítez 2 days ago had no effect.

Comment: I was misunderstanding the way macros were used. I thought the calls to create-user-menuitem with different callback symbols should have resulted in different callback functions which was incorrect thinking on my part. The use of lambda in a defun turns out to be the correct way to accomplish what I was attempting. Thank you, everyone for your help.

Comment: @pbowler happy to help. I would encourage you to keep writing and learning more about common lisp macros. My book recommendations on this topic are On Lisp and Let Over Lambda; Your original post touches on a lot of topics discussed in Let Over Lambda, just fyi